# Can I boot Windows 10 from a recovery USB?

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, bootable-media, portable

I am preparing to wipe out Windows 10 from an Asus laptop and install Linux Mint.  I don't expect to need to start up Windows again on this computer, but I would like to have the *option*, e.g. for any one-time runs of software that only works on Windows.

I believe what I need is a Windows recovery USB drive, but I can't seem to find out whether it's possible to simply *run* Windows from such a drive, or if I would have to reinstall it in order to use it just one time.

I don't want to set up dual boot.  I want to have no trace of Windows left on the computer itself, but I *do* want to have the option to start it up and run Windows by plugging in something first.

Can I do this with a Windows 10 recovery USB drive?  If not, what do I need to do to make this possible?

(I purchased the laptop new with Windows 10 pre-installed; it *does not* have a Windows key printed anywhere on the exterior.  I don't mind if the recovery or boot drive I make will *only* work with this specific laptop, so long as I don't have any problem about the Windows key and don't have to do a full reinstall just for a single session where I want to use Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

If you get the Recovery USB from ASUS (you should do this), you can recover directly. No third party tools needed. I have recovered my own machines (new drives) with the Vendor USB Key and it was painless and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks; is there a way to make that myself with an ASUS tool or is it only something that can be purchased from them?  (If the latter, I may just buy it later if I ever need it and go ahead and wipe the computer now.)  Should I get the Windows key off the computer somehow before wiping?

Comment: You may be able to make the Recovery USB from your system (I do this with my computers).. If that facility is not working, ASUS may ship you a Key for free or a small charge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes windows can be made run from a USB drive, you need third party tools for doing this. A guide to do this using Rufus or WinToUSB is available https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-run-windows-10-from-a-usb-drive. It first creates MBR/GPT partition and then copies files from the WIM images.